# Select the month in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I select the month in two different date columns? My original table is like

```
id occured_at                  expire_at
1  2017-03-17 10:21:22.935278  2017-04-17 10:21:22.935278
2  2017-04-24 10:21:22.93851   
3  2017-04-27 10:21:22.941801  2017-05-77 10:21:22.941801
4  2017-09-17 10:21:22.941801  2017-10-17 10:21:22.941801
```

and I want to select the either `occured_at` or `expire_at` in 2017-04, and also truncate the date to the year and month, the result is just like

```
id occured_at                  expire_at
1  2017-03                     2017-04
2  2017-04   
3  2017-04                     2017-05
```

I am a newbie in sql. it will be appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you’re using

Comment: sorry, I forget to remove the `mysql` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *display* the dates you want, use `to_char()`. The limit the number of rows you can use several different ways:

Using date_trunc:

```
select id, 
       to_char(occurred_at, 'yyyy-mm') as occurred_at,
       to_char(expire_at, 'yyyy-mm') as expire_at
from the_table
where date_trunc('month', occured_at) = date '2017-04-01'
   or date_trunc('month', expire_at) = date '2017-04-01';
```

or you can use compare formatted strings:

```
select id, 
       to_char(occurred_at, 'yyyy-mm') as occurred_at,
       to_char(expire_at, 'yyyy-mm') as expire_at
from the_table
where to_char(occured_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2017-04'
   or to_char(expire_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2017-04';
```

or you can use a range query:

```
select id, 
       to_char(occurred_at, 'yyyy-mm') as occurred_at,
       to_char(expire_at, 'yyyy-mm') as expire_at
from the_table
where (   occured_at >= timestamp '2017-04-01 00:00:00' 
      and occured_at < timestamp '2017-05-01 00:00:00')
   or (   expire_at >= timestamp '2017-04-01 00:00:00' 
      and expire_at < timestamp '2017-05-01 00:00:00');
```

The last query is able to use an index on those columns. For the first two queries you would need to define an expression index on the expression used.

Comment: The first solution I have been tried, and I have a little question, I run the code `SELECT id, date_trunc(occurred_at, 'yyyy-mm') AS month, date_trunc(expire_at, 'yyyy-mm') AS expireMonth FROM the_table WHERE '2017-04-01'' BETWEEN month AND expireMonth`. the result show that  the month and expireMonth columns don't exist. so my question is I can't use the new columns name to query? or I miss somthing

Comment: @Barry: that is a different question which has been answered many times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+alias+where+clause